# pyqt QTabWidget setCornerWidget TopRightCorner

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QTabWidget and add a set label to his upper right corner. When I set the width and height of the label, its border crosses the 'a' tab I added. I want to set the width and height of lalel. Do not cross the 'a' tab I added, how should I set

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTabWidget, QLabel
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Setting(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Setting, self).__init__()
        self.setText('setting')
        self.setStyleSheet("""*{border-width: 1px;
                                 border-style: solid;
                                 border-color: red;}""")
        self.setFixedSize(30, 40)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def create_tab(self):
        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel('a'), 'a')
        self.tab.setCornerWidget(Setting(), Qt.TopRightCorner)

    def initUI(self):
        self.create_tab()

        h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(h)
        h.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `setFixedSize()` from your label you can control the size and position through a stylesheet on the QTabWidget by targetting [`::right-corner`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#right-corner-sub).

```py
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def create_tab(self):
        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.tab.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabWidget::right-corner {
            width: 60px;
            height: 25px;
            subcontrol-position: left bottom;
        }''')
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel('a'), 'a')
        self.tab.setCornerWidget(Setting(), Qt.TopRightCorner)
```

Instead of `subcontrol-position` you can also use `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` with pixel values to shift the control around.